# Getting an error: "TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 3), <i4"

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

Here is a snippet of code with the goal of removing pixels from an image. I'm new to python I'm not sure if this is the right solution to begin with. The solution I've come up with is to convert the array to a 2-D list and remove each pixel (I tried np.delete, but it kept complaining that arrays must be rectangular), then back to an array, then back to an image as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def removeSeam(image, seam):
    """
    image: numpy array representing a PIL image
    seam: list of pixel coords represented as tuples in the form (x, y)
    returns a PIL image
    """
    grid = image.tolist()
    for i in range(len(seam)):
        grid[i].pop(seam[i][1])
    return Image.fromarray(np.array(grid))
```

The error is raised when I run something like this (traces back to the return statement in the function):

```
example = np.array([
    [[255, 255, 255], [0,    0,    0], [255, 255, 255]],
    [[0,    0,    0], [255, 255, 255], [0,    0,    0]],
    [[255, 255, 255], [0,    0,    0], [255, 255, 255]]])

# this seam should remove the top left, center, and bottom left pixels
seam = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2)]

removeSeam(example, seam)
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. I have no idea what `seam` is. If you're just trying to delete a row of pixels, you can do that with simple indexing. If it's a pixel per row, you can use fancy indexing. Otherwise, you won't have a 2D grid of pixels.

Comment: I don't see  "(1, 1, 3), <i4" in your code example.  Show the full traceback with the code that actually produced the error.

Comment: Just updated the code, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What is `seam` in general? Are you trying to get a method to remove one pixel per column?

Comment: My best explanation is that it's basically a path that, in this case, travels vertically from the top of the image to the bottom. It contains one pixel per row in the image, and removes it from each row, reducing the width of the image by one (this can also be done horizontally, but my code only supports vertical seams right now. More in-depth explanation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving).

Comment: Normally, row is the first index (axis 0) and column the second (axis 1). Is that something you can change in your code, or do you prefer that I work around it the way you have right now?

Comment: Thanks for updating BTW, and generally being responsive. I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting from an array to a list is rarely necessary and always expensive. An array packs data into a contiguous buffer, but a list wraps each element in a separate object and retains the pointers to those objects. That also means that arrays can be processed as entire units quite easily, while each object in a list requires independent handling. You almost never want to use a list to process imagery because of this.

As long as the seam is guaranteed to remove a single element from each row, you can remove it using the following steps:

1. View your `(r, c, 3)` array as a `(r * c, 3)` array. This does not involve copying any data.
2. Convert the indices of each seam element into a 1-D index.
3. Delete the required pixels from the 1D image. This will create a new array.
4. Reshape the result into `(r, c - 1, 3)`. This will not copy any data either.

I would recommend updating your code to support a seam of indices along the rows or columns, and an `axis` argument to `remove_seam`. That way, you only need to pass in a single array-like (including a list) that matches the size of the axis you are moving along:

```
def remove_seam(image, seam, axis=0):
    image = np.asanyarray(image)
    seam = np.asanyarray(seam)
    axis = np.core.multiarray.normalize_axis_index(axis, image.ndim)

    assert image.ndim == 3
    assert image.shape[-1] == 3
    assert axis in {0, 1}
    assert seam.size == image.shape[axis]

    shape = list(image.shape)
    seam = [seam, seam]
    seam[axis] = np.arange(image.shape[axis])
    seam = np.ravel_multi_index(seam, image.shape[:-1])
    image = image.reshape(-1, 3)
    shape[axis] -= 1
    result = np.delete(image, seam, axis=0).reshape(shape)
    return result
```

This may look much longer than your existing function, but it only performs one somewhat expensive operation: `np.delete(image, seam)`, and does that as cheaply as possible. If you look carefully at the other operations, they are just shuffling very small lists of numbers around to get the shapes and strides right.

Here is your example rewritten for the new interface:

```
example = np.array([
    [[255, 255, 255], [0,    0,    0], [255, 255, 255]],
    [[0,    0,    0], [255, 255, 255], [0,    0,    0]],
    [[255, 255, 255], [0,    0,    0], [255, 255, 255]]])

# this seam should remove the top left, center, and bottom left pixels
seam = [0, 1, 0]

remove_seam(example, seam)
```

This removes the top-left, middle, and bottom-left pixels. If you were to set `axis=1`, you would remove the top-left, middle and top-right pixels:

```
remove_seam(example, seam, axis=1)
```

To convert the array to an image, you need to convert it to `np.uint8` datatype. There are a couple of ways of doing this. One way is to make the input of the right size:

```
example = np.array([[[...]...]...], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Another is to convert the output:

```
remove_seam(...).astype(np.uint8)
```

The last way is to view the output as `np.uint8`, but you have to do this very carefully, including being aware of the endianness of the output:

```
remove_seam(...).view(np.uint8)[..., ::4]
```

Comment: Just tried running the code, and am coming across a ValueError on the np.delete line that says "cannot reshape array of size 24 into shape (2, 3, 3)". Also, is there any way to return an Image instead of an array? When I tried Image.fromarray() it raised the same error as before.

Comment: @sunbun. Sorry about that. Fixed the issue

Comment: @sunbun. By the way, your error has nothing to do with the code you posted and should have been a separate question. I've added the answer to it, but in future feel free to ask separate questions for separate problems.

Comment: Ah ok I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for the help!